# Некорректно отправляются данный в patch запрос

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, json, rest

```
import { Tab } from '@headlessui/react'
import Discharge from '../../../Components/Discharge';
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { PatchApiResource } from '../../../Requests/Patch';
import { DeleteApiResource } from '../../../Requests/Delete';

const fetchPatch = async (category, id) => {

  try {
    if (category !== null){
      // const response = await PatchApiResource(`${localStorage.getItem('url')}/field/${id}`, category)
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Ошибка при выполнении PATCH-запроса:', error);
  }
}
  
  const fetchDelete = async (id, removeCategory) => {

    try {
      const response = await DeleteApiResource(`${localStorage.getItem('url')}/field/${id}`)
      if (response){
        removeCategory(id)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Ошибка при выполнении DELETE-запроса:', error);
    }
  }

function Discharge2 ({categories, apiKey, idProvider, setCategories}){

    const { id } = useParams();

    const RefSettings = useRef();
    const RefDesiredName = useRef();
    const RefType = useRef();
    const RefUpgradable = useRef();

    const handler = (post) => {

      let valueSettings = RefSettings.current.value;
      let valueDesiredName = RefDesiredName.current.value;
      let valueType = RefType.current.value;
      let valueUpgradable = RefUpgradable.current.checked;

      console.log(post);
  
      const category = {
          title_from_provider: post.field_title,
          desired_title: valueDesiredName,
          ...(valueSettings && { settings: valueSettings }),
          upgradable: valueUpgradable,
          field_type: valueType,
          provider_id: id,
      };

      console.log(category, post.id)
      fetchPatch(category, post.id)
    };

    const removeCategory = (categoryIndex) => {
      setCategories((prevCategories) => {
        const updatedHandler = prevCategories["Выгрузка"].filter((index) => {
          return index.id !== categoryIndex;
        });
        return {
          ...prevCategories,
          ["Выгрузка"]: updatedHandler,
        };
      });
    };

    return (
        <Tab.Panel>
            <ul className="w-full m-1 mt-7">
                {categories.map((post) => (
                  post.is_active && (
                  <li
                    key={post.id}
                    className="relative w-full mt-4 group/item rounded-md p-3 bg-[#242F3D]"
                  >
                      <Discharge RefSettings={RefSettings} RefDesiredName={RefDesiredName} RefType={RefType} RefUpgradable ={RefUpgradable} post={post}/>

                      <div className="relative w-full flex justify-end items-center">
                        <button
                            className="font-mono flex items-center mt-4 mr-2 px-4 py-3 bg-red-500 text-white rounded-lg hover:bg-red-800"
                            onClick={() => {
                                fetchDelete(post.id, removeCategory)
                            }}
                            >
                            Удалить
                        </button>
                        </div>

                        <div className="relative w-full flex justify-end items-center">
                          <button
                            className="font-mono flex items-center mt-4 px-4 py-3 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-800"
                            onClick={() => handler(post)}
                          >
                            Изменить
                          </button>
                        </div>
                  </li>
                  )
                ))}
            </ul>
        </Tab.Panel>
    )
}

export default Discharge2;
```

Я принимаю json и распределяю его по li элементам, но когда я начинаю менять элемент он берёт все значения из последнего элемента categories и когда я хочу отправить значения в patch он отправляет значения последнего элемента и меняет он тоже только последний элемент, но в поле defaultValue он вставляет правильные значения для всех элементов post
Вот сама форма:

```
function Discharge ( {RefSettings, RefDesiredName, RefType, RefUpgradable, post} ){

    console.log(post, post.desired_title)
    return (
        <div className="w-full grid grid-cols-[minmax(0,1fr)_minmax(0,2fr)]">
            <div className="grid gap-4">
                <div className="relative w-max rounded-md bg-gray-700">
                    <label className="flex w-[150px] py-4 px-2.5 items-center">
                        <input 
                            type="checkbox" 
                            id="machine_name"
                            ref={RefUpgradable}
                            checked={post.upgradable || false}
                        />
                        
                        <span className="text-sm text-white ml-1 font-mono font-medium leading-5">
                            Автообновление
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div className="relative w-max flex items-center">
                    <label>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            id="desired_name" 
                            className={`peer relative w-[150px] bg-gray-700 border-none outline-none py-4 px-2.5 rounded-md 
                            text-white font-semibold text-base transition duration-300 shadow-sm placeholder-transparent`}
                            placeholder="URL"
                            autoComplete="off"
                            ref={RefDesiredName}
                            defaultValue={post.desired_title || ''}
                        />
                        <i className="i_field">Желаемое имя</i>
                    </label>
                </div>

                <div className="relative w-full flex items-center">
                    <label>
                        <input 
                            type="text" 
                            id="type" 
                            className={`peer relative w-[150px] bg-gray-700 border-none outline-none py-4 px-2.5 rounded-md 
                            text-white font-semibold text-base transition duration-300 shadow-sm placeholder-transparent`}
                            placeholder="URL"
                            autoComplete="off"
                            ref={RefType}
                            defaultValue={post.field_type || ''}
                        /> 
                        <i className="i_field">Тип поля</i>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="relative w-full">
                <h2 className="inline-block mb-3 text-[#fff] font-mono font-bold text-base">Дополнительные настройки</h2>

                <label>
                    <textarea
                        className="w-full max-h-[150px] overflow-y-auto bg-gray-700 border-none outline-none py-4 px-2.5 rounded-md text-white font-semibold overflow-hidden resize-y"
                        autoComplete="off"
                        ref={RefSettings}
                        defaultValue={post.settings || ''}
                    />
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Discharge;
```

Comment: Так вы каждый раз ref переопределяете. Вот поэтому ваши рефы смотрят на последний элемент

Comment: А как можно сделать чтобы для каждого input определялся свой ref?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделайте input контролируемыми. Добавте им имена (аналогичный ключу в объекте post) и событие onChange, по которому при редактировании будет обновляться исходный объект categories (для этого у вас есть post.id). имхо ref тут совершенно лишний.
Получится что-то типа:

```
<textarea
  name="settings"
  className="w-full max-h-[150px] ///"
  autoComplete="off"
  value={post.settings || ""}
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e, post.id)}
/>
```

B Discharge2 ты получаешь (как я понимаю) массив categories. Я бы его сохранял в стайт и обновлял бы его по мере редактирования.

```
const [data, setData] = React.useState(categories)

const handleChange = (e, id) => {
 const {name, value, } = e.target;
 const newData = data.map((i) => {
  return i.id !== id ? i : { ...i, [name]: value };
 });
 setData(newData);
};
```